# How to immediately display Ownerdrawn Listview Header Line

Tags: listview, winapi, header, ownerdrawn

I use the below code to subclass a Windows ListView header control. My procedure works fine and responds well to mouse hover over the header control.

My issue is when I create a big list "for the first time", The header line does not show till the list is fully populated:

[image: Header line during loading big list 1st time]

Then, if I delete the opened list and create a new one, or even the same old one, the header line shows immediately, not waiting for the list to be completed:

[image: Header line during loading big list 2nd time]

If I do not subclass the header control, native Windows procedure always shows the header line immediately, not waiting for the list to be completed, but then I lose my customization.

Any suggestion what I am missing to get the header line to show immediately?

Note:

I call `LockWindowUpdate()` before starting and after finishing adding list view items. I tried to not call `LockWindowUpdate()`, but the result was the header line does not show even after finishing adding all the items, it waits till I force a new `WM_PAINT` msg by moving the mouse over the header line.

Here is my subclass function:

```
static char* HeaderText[20] = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J",
                               "K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T"} ;


LRESULT APIENTRY HeaderSubclassProc (HWND hwnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)                         
{
static  int     y ;
static  int     xe ;
static  int     xr ;
static  int     HBtn = -1 ;
static  RECT    Hrc ;
static  HPEN    Pen ;
static  HPEN    HPen ;
static  HBRUSH  Brush ;
static  HBRUSH  HBrush ;
static  TRACKMOUSEEVENT  tme = {sizeof (TRACKMOUSEEVENT),TME_LEAVE,NULL,
                                HOVER_DEFAULT} ;
HDC     hDC ;

switch (msg) {
    RECT    rc ;

    case IDM_INIT :
        Pen    = CreatePen (PS_SOLID,0,0xF2F2F2) ;
        HPen   = CreatePen (PS_SOLID,0,0xF88420) ;
        Brush  = CreateSolidBrush (0xD2D2D2) ;
        HBrush = CreateSolidBrush (0xFFEFE0) ;
        Header_GetItemRect (hwnd,19,&rc) ;
        xr = rc.right ;
        tme.hwndTrack = hwnd ;
        return 0 ;

    case WM_CLOSE :
        DeleteObject (Pen) ;
        DeleteObject (HPen) ;
        DeleteObject (Brush) ;
        DeleteObject (HBrush) ;
        return 0 ;

    case WM_SIZE :
        TEXTMETRIC  tm ;
        hDC = GetDC (hwnd) ;
        GetTextMetrics (hDC,&tm) ;
        ReleaseDC (hwnd,hDC) ;
        Header_GetItemRect (hwnd,0,&rc) ;
        y = (rc.bottom - rc.top - tm.tmHeight) / 2 + tm.tmAscent ;
        xe = LOWORD (lParam) ;
        break ;

    case WM_MOUSELEAVE :
        HBtn = -1 ;
        InvalidateRect (hwnd,&Hrc,true) ;
        return 0 ;

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE :
        int x ;
        x = LOWORD (lParam) ;
        if (HBtn > -1 && x > xr) {
            HBtn = -1 ;
            InvalidateRect (hwnd,&Hrc,true) ;
            break ;
        } /* if (HLBtn == 19 && x > xr) */
        for (int Btn = 0 ; Btn < 20 ; Btn++) {
            Header_GetItemRect (hwnd,Btn,&rc) ;
            if (x > rc.left && x < rc.right) {
                if (Btn == HBtn)
                    break ;
                HBtn = Btn ;
                Hrc = rc ;
                InvalidateRect (hwnd,NULL,true) ;
                break ;
            } /* if (x > rc.left && x < rc.right) */
        } /* for (int Btn = 0 ; Btn < 20 ; Btn++) */
        TrackMouseEvent (&tme) ;
        break ;

    case WM_PAINT :
        PAINTSTRUCT ps ;
        hDC = BeginPaint (hwnd,&ps) ;
        int DefDC = SaveDC (hDC) ;

        SelectObject (hDC,Pen) ;
        SelectObject (hDC,Brush) ;
        SetTextAlign (hDC,TA_BASELINE | TA_CENTER) ;
        SetBkMode (hDC,TRANSPARENT) ;

        for (int Btn = 0 ; Btn < 20 ; Btn++) {
            if (Btn == HBtn)
                continue ;
            Header_GetItemRect (hwnd,Btn,&rc) ;
            int x = (rc.right + rc.left) / 2 ;
            Rectangle (hDC,rc.left,rc.top,rc.right + 1,rc.bottom) ;
            ExtTextOut (hDC,x,y,ETO_NUMERICSLATIN,&rc,HeaderText[Btn],
                            (UINT) strlen (HeaderText[Btn]),NULL) ;
        } /* for (int Btn = 0 ; Btn < 20 ; Btn++) */
        Rectangle (hDC,rc.right,rc.top,xe,rc.bottom) ;

        if (HBtn > -1 ) {
            Header_GetItemRect (hwnd,HBtn,&rc) ;
            x = (rc.right + rc.left) / 2 ;
            SelectObject (hDC,HPen) ;
            SelectObject (hDC,HBrush) ;
            Rectangle (hDC,rc.left + 1,rc.top + 1,rc.right,rc.bottom - 1) ;
            ExtTextOut (hDC,x,y,ETO_NUMERICSLATIN,&rc,HeaderText[HBtn],
                            (UINT) strlen (HeaderText[HBtn]),NULL) ;
        } /* if (HLBtn > -1 ) */

        RestoreDC (hDC,DefDC) ;
        EndPaint (hwnd,&ps) ;
        return 0 ;

} /* switch (msg) */

return CallWindowProc ((WNDPROC) DefaultHeaderProc,hwnd,msg,wParam,lParam) ;

} /* HeaderSubclassProc */
```

Comment: Maybe you need to Invalidate the list somehow?

Answer (score 2):

You definitely SHOULD NOT be using `LockWindowUpdate()` at all (there are numerous articles on [Raymond Chen's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/) explaining why).

The correct solution is to send the ListView a [`WM_SETREDRAW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145219.aspx) message to disable its drawing until you are done with your updates, then send `WM_SETREDRAW` again to re-enable drawing, and finally trigger a repaint with [`InvalidateRect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145002.aspx)/[`UpdateWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145167.aspx), or [`RedrawWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162911.aspx).

Alternatively, [use the ListView in virtual mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh270411.aspx), especially if you are going to be showing a lot of items.

Comment: I tried WM_SETREDRAW and it does not solve the problem. Again it works for the native Windows Header procedure but not for subclassed Header. It even worsen the problem as I could not programmatically redraw the Header after finish the list. InvalidateRect() / UpdateWindow() and RedrawWindow() failed to show the Header. I have to manually cover/uncover the window to show the Header. I believe something is missing in my subclass processing of WM_PAINT, but can not figure it out.

Comment: You haven't shown how you are subclassing the ListView header, or how you are populating the ListView items.